# Motor choice for quietest (mechanical and electrical) operation

Tags: motor

Which types of motor are the most quiet from a mechanical and electrical point of view? To avoid quiet, but weak, suggestions, the motor needs to be capable of about 70 Nm of torque and speed range from 600 to 2400 rpm.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a product recomendation, which is against the rules of this website. If I am incorrect, let me know, and edit the question so it is more obvious you are not seeking a product recomendation. Try to be more specific in your questioning. Good luck, and welcome to EE SE!

Comment: I would first look at servo motors and induction motors. The drive units for these are not electrically quiet, but they can be acoustically quiet if the carrier frequency is 20kHz or above. You will have to work on filtering and shielding etc to keep the electric noise under control. Fans for the drive unit and possibly the motor will probably be the largest source of acoustic noise (assuming you can find one with a high carrier frequency).

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered a hydraulic motor?

Have the pump power unit remote in another room for example, which keeps that vibration separate.

The speed is achievable and can be finely controlled.

There won't be any electromagnetic interference produced which seems to be one of your important parameters (electrical noise).

Comment: Is 2400 RPM achievable?

Comment: @mkeith Yes, some do 5000rpm, check out this for examples of what you might need : https://www.boschrexroth.com/en/us/products/product-groups/industrial-hydraulics/motors/axial-piston-motors/fixed-motors

Answer (score 0):

You can either use asynchronous motor or synchronous motor 
Asynchronous motors is quiet compared to synchronous but their speed highly depends on load and frequency .
Synchronous make little bit more noise because it has brushes to make magnetic poles but you can adjust the speed by lowering the DC current in magnetic poles